# Is it safe to remove a plug, and wire a light fitting into the wall?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, switch

I've moved into a house, and am fitting a series of 5 halogen downlights beneath a shelving unit. The wall on which I am fitting it previously had an uplighter. I removed this so now have exposed live, neutral and (unsheathed) earth wires on the wall. This is already operated by a light switch on another wall.

The new lights I have come with a fitted fused (3 amp) plug. The instructions say if it is installed directly on a lighting circuit it will need a 5 amp fuse.

So - if I want to wire it directly, can I assume the lighting circuit is adequately protected since it already had a light fixture (is this standard?), or for this fitting do I need to install an (unswitched) fused spur or something similar to add the 5 amp protection?

---

To clarify, the 5 halogen lights are wired into one fitting with a transformer leading to one plug.

Comment: From the OP's profile, the location appears to be the UK.

Comment: @Tester101 outside of a plug? In a spur then? Here's the [product link](http://www.homebase.co.uk/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?langId=110&storeId=10151&partNumber=731418) (this might not be the exact model). Its instructions were a bit brief and I want to be sure.

Comment: Not exactly. The plug itself is fused with 3A, which is then connected to the primary of the transformer. I want to remove the plug. Would these lights require a fuse when the previous did not, or is this just a precaution?

Comment: @Tester101 thanks. So I can assume the lighting circuit isn't itself fused, that this is conventional and that the previous light was deliberately unfused?

Comment: @Tester101 Ah I think you have answered my question. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Comments converted to answer.**

If the manufacturer says they need a fuse, then I'd probably install a fuse. Just install a 5A fuse before the transformer, and make sure it's accessible in some way.

The light circuit is probably on a fuse/breaker at the service panel, but since you are using a transformer to step down to low voltage a fuse may be required to protect the transformer and low voltage wiring. The fuse/breaker in the main panel will probably be 15-20A; since it's designed to protect a normal line voltage lighting circuit, so you'll need another 5A fuse before the step down transformer to protect the transformer and everything downstream from it.

Comment: I will attach a 5 amp fuse, thanks @Tester101

Comment: @Tester101, what's the proper fuse holder to use in this situation? And does it go inside a junction box?

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens Not sure, I'd have to do some research on that. Typically there would be parts supplied with the equipment, if this was a typical/valid installation method.

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens I intend to use a fused spur (or FCU) and place it below my shelving unit. That way I have access to a plate with the fuse in case anything goes awry. They seem to generally be available with a 13A limit, which is more than enough for my needs.

Comment: @waj: A fused connection unit (FCU) is probably appropriate but, to protect the wire to the transformer you should fit the FCU with a 3 (three) amp fuse (e.g. use the one from the plug you remove). The wire is sized for 3A but the lighting circuit can provide more than that, enough to start a fire in the wire to the transformer in the event of a fault.